# Consultar tempo de execução de instruções realizadas no Banco

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um trabalho de analise de desempenho aonde fiz um script em js que realiza as seguintes etapas:

1: executo 1000 inserts depois 2000 e assim por diante.
2: faço um update de 500 inserts depois de 1000, dentre outras funções do CRUD.

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu coletar o tempo de execução para depois eu extrair e jogar em um gráfico e manipular.

Se sim onde posso encontrar esses registro?

Resumindo gostaria de pegar o tempo que ele mostra logo apos realizamos uma operação direto no banco como a seguinte:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO myset (col) VALUES ('a,d,d,s');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

no caso de um inserte 0.03 sec gostaia de pegar os do meus 1000 inserts e assim por diante, existe algum log aonde isso fica registrado?